# Wireshark can't see cellular activity on Win10 tablet

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireshark, sniffing, cellular

I'm running Windows 10 Enterprise x64 on an HP Pro x2 612 G1 Tablet, with a Verizon SIM card to allow cellular data connectivity. I've installed Wireshark 2.2.1 and can't see any activity on any of the connections when launching the app:

[image]

If I plug in the Ethernet cable into the tablet, the Ethernet line starts showing activity. However, when on cellular (the last connection listed above), I'm able to connect to the Web just fine; however, Wireshark shows no activity.